# winform in console application

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, console-application

I have a console application which can also open winform under certain    conditions.Processing(its a database export utility) and be done either through form or commandline. but the form is always associated with command prompt. i mean when i close the console the form get closed as well.My requirement is that when form is launched , the command prompt is closed by itself without closing the form.

```
  [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

         if(hastolaunchform)
          {
                  Application.Run(new Form1());
           }

         else
           {
                       Console.WriteLine("started");
                        try
                        {
                            dataclass.extract();
                            console.writeline("finish");
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("An error occur");
                        }
             }

         }
```

Comment: Parse error: Question not found.

Comment: sorry I couldn't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is an app that has a gui **or** not.

What you need is a gui version of it that optionally can be run from the CLI, ie it needs to be another exe, or the same exe with different command line parameters, though be careful with that, otherwise it could just keep launching another version of itself until windows dies.

At least I think that's what you are asking.

CLI arguments

MyApp.Exe --GUI

--GUI will apears in args[1].

So something like

```
if (args.Contains["--GUI"])
{
   Application.Run(new Form1());
}
else
{
  if (hastolaunchForm)
  {
     // use Process.start to run another version of your app with --GUI parameter
     // and close
  }
  else
  {
     // do console stuff.
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes that's pretty much it. Could you please explain second one "same exe with different command line parameters" with simple code.

Comment: Are you building winform or the console application for this. I could not understand how the form and console are independent now.

Comment: It's both now, so I assumed you wanted to keep it that way. Building one of each and sticking data and or logic layers in a dll is a good idea though. Given a choice I wouldn't have started where you did, and took the 'nix approach, as in separate out the UI, so one console app and one gui, given my druthers.

Comment: If build seperate project for both but still the console is the starting point.when we run the console without parameter exe open up or else run from commandline. How would you invoke the exe from console.

Comment: ok. what is the project type(console or window) of this project in the vs solution since we have only single project now?

Comment: It's only a template, a starter for ten, as soon as you changed program.cs, that went in the bin. One console, one winders, one dll project, or just one that does either, or one that does either + a dll, depends on whether you are happier with one or two exes, thats all.